# Micro scheduler for real-time kernel in embedded C applications?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, embedded, real-time, scheduler

I am working with time-critical applications where the microsecond counts. I am interested to a more convenient way to develop my applications using a non bare-metal approach (some kind of framework or base foundation common to all my projects).

A considered real-time operating system such as RTX, Xenomai, Micrium or VXWorks are not really real-time under my terms (or under the terms of electronic engineers). So I prefer to talk about *soft-real-time* and *hard-real-time* applications. An *hard-real-time* application has an acceptable jitter less than 100 ns and a heat-beat of 100..500 microseconds (tick timer).

After lots of readings about operating systems I realized that typical tick-time is 1 to 10 milliseconds and only one task can be executed each tick. Therefore the tasks take usually much more than one tick to complete and this is the case of most available operating systems or micro kernels.

For my applications a typical task has a duration of 10..100 microseconds, with few exceptions that can last for more than one tick. So any *real-time* operating system cannot not fulfill my requirements. That is the reason why other engineers still not consider operating system, micro or nano kernels because the way they work is too far from their needs. I still want to struggle a bit and in my case I now realize I have to consider a new category of operating system that I never heard about (and that may not exist yet). Let's  call this category *nano-kernel* or *subtick-scheduler*

In such dreamed kernels I would find:

- 2 types of tasks:

  - Preemptive tasks (that run in their own memory space)
  - Non-preemptive tasks (that run in the kernel space and must complete in less than one tick.
- Deterministic kernel scheduler (fixed duration after the ISR to reach the theoretical zero second jitter)
- Ability to run multiple tasks per tick

For a better understanding of what I am looking for I made this figure below that represents the two types or kernels. The first representation is the traditional kernel. A task executes at each tick and it may interrupt the kernel with a system call that invoke a full context switch.

The second diagram shows a sub-tick kernel scheduler where multiple tasks may share the same tick interrupt. **Task 1** was summoned with a maximum execution time value so it needs 2 ticks to complete. **Task 2** is set with low priority, so it consumes the remaining time of each tick upon completion. **Task 3** is non-preemptive so it operates on the kernel space which save some precious context switch time.

[image]

Available operating systems such as RTOS, RTAI, VxWorks or µC/OS are not fully real-time and are not suitable for embedded hard real-time applications such as motion-control where a typical cycle would last no more than 50 to 500 microseconds. By analyzing my needs I land on different topology for my scheduler were multiple tasks can be executed under the same tick interrupt. Obviously I am not the only one with this kind of need and my problem might simply be a kind of X-Y problem. So said differently I am not really looking at what I am really looking for.

After this (pretty) long introduction I can formulate my question:

What could be a good existing architecture or framework that can fulfill my requirements other than a naive bare-metal approach where everything is written sequentially around one master interrupt? If this kind of framework/design pattern exists what would it be called?

Comment: You posit that none of those existing OS's can meet your needs because they "typically" have a tick time of 1-10ms.  Those typical tick times are driven by the needs of the applications built on that OS.  Nothing is stopping you from having a faster system tick than typical, provided you understand the overhead added during faster ticks.  And in lieu of all of this focus on time (50-500 microseconds), I suggest you consider thinking in terms of cpu cycles.  500us on a 100MHz clock is a lot different than 500us on a 1Mhz clock...

Comment: You are right, I would have better used CPU cycles. In my case my CPU has a 3ns cycle and a typical full interrupt context switch requires about 500 cycles. Increasing the tick time of a heavy POSIX kernel is not an option so I am afraid standard operating system is not an option in my case.

Comment: Have you considered the [QP active object framework](http://www.state-machine.com/)?

Comment: @kkrambo Not yet, I am going to take a look to it.

Comment: Note that real-time kernels do not need to use tick-driven scheduling. They can use co-operative scheduling, in which your tasks give up the CPU voluntarily.- thus you determine entirely how you want your tasks to spend their time. (Though that is not a good approach if you don't know or cannot control how long a task runs before it yields the CPU). Even with a tick-driven approach, your tasks can  ofcourse yield the CPU, and another task will be scheduled immediately, not at the end of a tick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but first of all, let me say that your entire post is completely wrong and shows complete lack of understanding how preemptive RTOS works.

> After lots of readings about operating systems I realized that typical tick-time is 1 to 10 milliseconds and only one task can be executed each tick.

**This is completely wrong.**

In reality, a tick frequency in RTOS determines only two things:

1. resolution of timeouts, sleeps and so on,
2. context switch due to round-robin scheduling (where two or more threads with the same priority are "runnable" at the same time for a long period of time.

During a single tick - which typically lasts 1-10ms, but you can usually configure that to be whatever you like - scheduler can do hundreds or thousands of context switches. Or none. When an event arrives and wakes up a thread with sufficiently high priority, context switch will happen **immediately**, not with the next tick. An event can be originated by the thread (posting a semaphore, sending a message to another thread, ...), interrupt (posting a semaphore, sending a message to a queue, ...) or by the scheduler (expired timeout or things like that).

There are also RTOSes with no system ticks - these are called "tickless". There you can have resolution of timeouts in the range of nanoseconds.

> That is the reason why other engineers still not consider operating system, micro or nano kernels because the way they work is too far from their needs.

Actually this is a reason why these "engineers" should read something instead of pretending to know everything and seeking "innovative" solutions to non-existing problems. This is completely wrong.

> The first representation is the traditional kernel. A task executes at each tick and it may interrupt the kernel with a system call that invoke a full context switch.

This is not a feature of a RTOS, but the way you wrote your application - if a high priority task is constantly doing something, then lower priority tasks will *NOT* get any chance to run. But this is just because you assigned wrong priorities.

Unless you use cooperative RTOS, but if you have such high requirements, why would you do that?

> The second diagram shows a sub-tick kernel scheduler where multiple tasks may share the same tick interrupt.

This is exactly how *EVERY* preemptive RTOS works.

> Available operating systems such as RTOS, RTAI, VxWorks or µC/OS are not fully real-time and are not suitable for embedded hard real-time applications such as motion-control where a typical cycle would last no more than 50 to 500 microseconds.

Completely wrong. In every known RTOS it is not a problem to get a response time down to single microseconds (1-3us) with a chip that has clock in the range of 100MHz. So you actually can run "jobs" which are as short as 10us without too much overhead. You can even have "jobs" as short as 10ns, but then the overhead will be pretty high...

> What could be a good existing architecture or framework that can fulfill my requirements other than a naive bare-metal approach where everything is written sequentially around one master interrupt? If this kind of framework/design pattern exists what would it be called?

This pattern is called preemptive RTOS. Do note that threads in RTOS are *NOT* executed in "tick interrupt". They are executed in standard "thread" context, and tick interrupt is only used to switch context of one thread to another.

What you described in your post is a "cooperative" RTOS, which does *NOT* preempt threads. You use that in systems with extremely limited resources and with low timing requirements. In every other case you use preemptive RTOS, which is capable of handling the events **immediately**.

Comment: This is a bit rude, but a very useful answer. I have indeed misunderstood how operating systems work and you pointed it out. You answer will help me to dig further in such matter. Do you have any references of such cooperative RTOS or tickless kernels usable for very jitter sensitive applications?

Comment: @nowox - recommendations depend on the type of hardware you have. A completely different RTOS will have to be used if we talk about a 8-bit chip, something much bigger can be used if you have a 32-bit chip with a lots of RAM, and a completely different approach is required when you are working on a SoC (ar a "processor" instead of "microcontroller") with external RAM, MMU and so on.

Comment: @nowox For example I've written a C++ RTOS myself (http://distortos.org/), but it's main target are 32-bit microcontrollers from the "higher" end (like ARM Cortex-M). You probably wouldn't want to use that on an 8-bit AVR, just as you wouldn't like to use that on a hardware from your smartphone.

Comment: I use a SHARC processor from Analog Devices (450 MHz, 5Mbits SRAM, SIMD). My primary goal is to run two main threads ticked at 50us and 200us with other low priority threads that share the remaining computation power.

Comment: @nowox Your best bet is to just google for an RTOS which is ported to this particular type of chip. In theory you could take just any RTOS and port that yourself, but this is obviously not so easy. Taking something which is known to work is a good approach especially if you're new to this stuff. This is pretty old, but maybe still relevant https://ez.analog.com/thread/1914 Generally this is typical that the chip vendor provides a package with some RTOS (in-house solution or a port of some open-source project), so start by searching AD's website.